PHP Google cloud function got OpenSSL Error messages: "CURL error 35: error:0A000126:SSL routines: unexpected eof while reading"
I'm running a Google Cloud Function to perform an asynchronous task using pcntl_fork and Guzzle Client to handle external API requests .
When I make an external API request to a third-party service, I encounter the following OpenSSL error if the JSON request body is too large: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
However, when the request body is smaller, everything works fine, and the error does not occur.
Has anyone encountered this issue or know why this error happens only with larger request bodies? How can I resolve this?
Here are related code
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class forkService
{
    public function callAndForget(callable $resolve, callable $reject = null): void
    {
        if (!function_exists('pcntl_fork')) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('pcntl_fork is not available');
        }

        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if ($pid == -1) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Could not fork process');
        } elseif ($pid === 0) {
            // Child process
            try {
                $resolve();
            } catch (\Throwable $e) {
                if ($reject !== null) {
                    $reject($e);
                }
            }
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

and the place call it is
$this->forkService->callAndForget(function () use ($data) {
    $this->processingService->pushData($data);
});

class ProcessingService
{
    private Client $client;

    public function __construct(
        private readonly LogService $logService,
        ?HandlerStack               $clientStack = null,
    ) {
        $stack = HandlerStack::create($clientStack);
        $stack->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function ($request) {
            $fullUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
            $method  = (string) $request->getMethod();
            $this->logService->info("Send [{$method}] request to URL: {$fullUrl}");

            return $request;
        }));

        $this->client = new Client(['handler' => $stack]);
    }

    public function pushData(string $data): void
    {
        try {
            $path           = $this->buildPath($data);
            $fileName       = $data['fileName'];
            $requestOptions = $this->prepareRequestOptions($data);
            $requestOptions['json'] = /* this should be an array of processing object inside of $data passed, it size can be a lot*/  

            $this->client->post($path, $requestOptions);
            $this->logService->info("Success");
        } catch (Exception|GuzzleException $e) {
            $this->logService->error("Error");
        }
    }
}

The only step I've taken so far is removing all null values from the request body to reduce its size, but the issue persists, likely because there's still a large amount of data being sent.
Once again "when the request body is smaller, everything works fine, and the error does not occur."
Can it be related to Gloud Function that it couldn't handle large request? (but I believe my request size are not that big of limit from Glouc Function)
Beside this I use php 8.3 and
"php-di/php-di": "^7.0",
"nikic/fast-route": "^1.3",

for container injection and simulate a controller like routing for one function instead of using a whole Laravel with GCloud Function
/// Updated
I used GCloud Function V2 for this one
/// Sep 23 Updated
So the main issue stems from running an asynchronous task in an environment that isn't designed for it.
And my team is trying to deploy Cloud Functions on Kubernetes. Does anyone have any insights on this??

Not a PHP dev. It's possible that the Cloud Function is either timing out before the completion of all the uploads and the forked processes are being killed and/or your exceeding allocated memory (OOM). You don't describe which Cloud Functions variant you're using but both default to 60 seconds. You should be able to gain better insight using a combination of the logs and metrics.

@DazWilkin I used V2 for this, and I'll provide further updates on the logging soon.

I would venture to guess that CloudFunctions does not care about any PID but the parent, so when the parent exits the container shuts down including the forked child. The likely relation to the payload size is that smaller payloads are able to complete before the container shuts down. If you want to execute a task asynchronously, then I would suggest another CloudFunction. Relevant doc, see "Why you should try to avoid async work in a Function".

The third party that you are calling is abruptly closing the connection. They don't like the request your code is sending. Ask their support why. Besides limiting the size of the request body and making sure the request is valid, there is not much you can do in your code to solve this. Suggestion, do not use vague terms, specify the actual numbers, and not descriptions like "too large"

@JohnHanley sorry for that, but because running it locally working just all fine, also when I remove the callAndForget function to fork a child process, meaning I have to wait for the whole response and it work all just fine, so I dont think it related to the 3rd party but the async call itself

It is my first time asking question on stackoverflow, Thank you for the suggestion!

Welcome to StackOverflow. The details in your comment should be in your question. If something works in one environment document that. I think you are misusing the design for Cloud Functions. It is a simple HTTP Request/Response system, not an operating system. Don't do things like forking processes/threads. Also remember when the request returns, your app is dead. At least read the docs on what is supported. Perhaps consider Google Cloud run which is the big brother to Cloud Functions. I think its design better suits your application.

Thanks! This situation is frustrating because I discussed it with another engineer who has the authority to decide on the design. Initially, I advised the team against using that approach and suggested an alternative, provide some evidence to support my opinion, we dont even make a background task to run but casually waiting for the response, which handled by a job dispatch from the main service. However, they insisted they had experience with it, and I felt I didn’t have the authority to make the decision. I was following their lead (my bad), and now we’re facing the consequences

After raising the issues with the team, other higher-priority tasks took over, and this one was pushed aside. Meanwhile, they set up the new Kubernetes environment and are trying to deploy the cloud functions there, which has left me feeling quite confused. Do you know anything about using Cloud Functions with Kubernetes? @JohnHanley

@givemesomevalue - I do not know anything about Cloud Functions on Kubernetes. You say that you don't even make a background task, but then why are you calling pcntl_fork() in your code? Cloud Functions is for small, fast, and lightweight code.

Sorry, I meant when we first implement it, I don't use the background task until the lead want the response to be return right away as a response of Request Acknowledge, and have the process running behind
